# Reaproveitamento/reuso de componente com reatividade no Vue

Tags: vue.js, componentes

Estou tentando reaproveitar componentes no **VueJS**, uma das minhas tentativas é para reaproveitar campos de formulários, exemplo:

Tenho em diversos formulários do meu site os campos *login* e *password*, então criei um componente chamado `userform`:

```
<template>
    <section>
        <input v-model="login">
        <input v-model="password" type="password">
    </section>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "userform",
    data(){
        return {
            login: 'blabla',
            password: ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

A ideia agora é pegar o componente `userform` criado e reusar em diversos componentes para formar formulários, por exemplo no componente de `login`:

```
<template>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

        <userform></userform>
        <button @click="sendLogin()">
            Logar
        </button>

    </section>
</template>

<script>

import userform from './../../forms/userform.vue'

export default {
    name: "login",
    components: {userform},
    mixins: [userform],
    methods: {
        sendLogin() {
            console.log( "Usuario " +  userform.data().login )
            console.log( "Senha " + userform.data().password )
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Mas a reatividade não funciona, quando entro no componente `login` os dados de *login* e *password* até são pegos, mas nunca são alterados, sempre a saída no console é:

```
Usuario blabla
Senha
```

Como faço para que a reatividade funcione nesse caso? Estou usando da maneira certa? Poderiam dar um exemplo de como é feito esse tipo de reaproveitamento? Estou com dificuldade de aprender essa parte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Componentes servem para serem reaproveitados, não seria necessária a utilização do *mixin*, que é reaproveitamento de fragmentos de componentes.

Você tem dois problemas aí:

### ***Mixin*** injeta valores dentro de componentes, mas seus valores não são compartilhados

O ***Mixin*** serve para que você não precise repetir códigos em componentes distintos que tenham alguma função/dado em comum, mas eles não são compartilhados entre si, se você altera um, não altera o do outro, o *Vue* não permite isso¹.
Como você está usando o ***mixin*** dentro do componente ***`login`*** que está comportando seu componente ***`userform`***, você está apenas replicando o valor de ***`userform`*** dentro de ***`login`*** (você pode conferir no [VueDevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)).

[image: O componente Login também tem os valores, mas a reatividade só acontece no userform]

Mas isso não é o causador do seu problema, vamos então a ele...

### Chamar ***`userform`*** diretamente, faz com que você selecione o objeto ***`userform`*** do componente ***`Login`*** importado e não o componente ***`userform`*** em si.

Não sei com certeza se esse é o comportamento, mas ao chamar ***`userform`*** você está chamando o objeto instanciado dentro de `components: { userform }`, pois pense comigo, e se você tivesse 2 tags `<userform>`, qual você acessaria? A reatividade é inerente a cada componente, de forma independente.

[tl;dr]
Por isso ele pega o valor do objeto ***`userform`***, que está com os valores pré-definidos, que só se alterarão se você mexer no objeto, mas mesmo assim, sem alterar o valor dos componentes, que já são outros objetos.

### Solução: [Referência](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)

Uma forma de contornar esse problema é utilizando as referências.
Para utilizá-las, você deve adicionar propriedade `ref` no componente e acessá-la usando
`this.$refs.nome_da_ref.nome_do_dado`.

**Ex(componente myComponent.vue):**

```
<template>
  <input v-model='x'>
</template>  
<script>
export default {
  data (){
    return {
      x: 10
    }
  }
}
<script>
```

**Ex(Componente teste.vue):**

```
<template>
  <my-component ref='meuComponent'>
</template>
<script>
import myComponent from './myComponent'

export default {
  components: { myComponent }
  methods: {
    showData() {
      console.log(this.$refs.x);
    }
  }
}
<script>
```

Assim que você alterar o valor do input do `<my-component>` a reatividade funciona e o método `showData()` *printará* o valor digitado.

### Resultado

Algumas alterações precisam ser feiras no componente ***login***:

1. Remova o *mixin*
2. Adicione a referência
3. Altere seu método para utilizar a referência no lugar do objeto

**Código:**

```
<template>
    <section class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

        <userform ref='meuForm'></userform>
        <button @click="sendLogin()">
            Logar
        </button>

    </section>
</template>

<script>

import userform from './../../forms/userform.vue'

export default {
    name: "login",
    components: {userform},
    methods: {
        sendLogin() {
            console.log( "Usuario " +  this.$refs.meuForm.login )
            console.log( "Senha " + this.$refs.meuForm.password )
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Isso deve resolver.

### Recomendações e Convenções

- Se quer utilizar um mesmo dado de forma global, para diversos componentes na mesma view, sugiro que dê uma olhada no ***[Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)***.
- Utilize algum prefixo em seus componentes, isso poderá evitar dores de cabeça mais tarde (componentes de terceiros com o mesmo nome, componentes já existentes no HTML, etc).
  Ex: `<lvcsUserForm>` ou `<lvcs-user-form>`.
- Trate componentes como objetos que são, utilizando *camelCase* em seus nomes durante o `import`, e repita-os nos arquivos.
  Isso até te ajuda, não sendo necessário o atributo `name` no componente, e ele poderá ter sua tag escrita de duas formas, com ***PascalCase*** ou ***kebab-case***, mas isso é definido pelo nome utilizado no `import`, como `import MeuForm from './../../forms/userform'` poderá ser usado como `<MeuForm>` ou `<meu-form>`.

***Obs:** O mesmo não funciona para `props`, elas devem ser nomeadas em ***camelCase*** e sempre serão escritas em ***kebab-case*** no componente, eg. `<meu-form my-prop="10">`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tinha pesquisado sobre isso mas era tudo usando o `emit`, que eu acho que seria mais para comunicação entre os componentes e não referências entre valores. Esclareceu muito!

Comment: O $emit geralmente é utilizado para soltar uma *flag* (dar um sinal) de que algo aconteceu, o problema é que o componente filho lança o valor para o pai, mas pra isso tem que existir um evento\*, algo tem que acontecer no filho, logo, não existe reatividade.

\* A função e o botão enviar teriam que estar no userform

Comment: Isso sim eu chamo de resposta ! Era bem isso, obrigado !